# .net object equality

Tags: c#, .net

Lets say we have two objects o1 & o2 defined as System.Object, in my situtaion o1 & o2 can be any of the following types:

- String
- Int32
- Double
- Boolean
- DateTime
- DBNull

So how can I check that o1 & o2 are equal, therefore are the same object or both have the same type & value.

Can I just do `o1 == o2` or do I need to do `o1.Equals(o2)` or something else?

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would suggest you use

```
object.Equals(o1, o2)
```

as that will cope with nullity as well. (That assumes you want two null references to compare as equal.)

You should *not* use `==` because operators are not applied polymorphically; the types *overload* == but they don't *override* it (there's nothing to override). If you use

```
o1 == o2
```

that will compare them for *reference identity*, because the variables are declared to be of type `object`.

Using `o1.Equals(o2)` will work *except* in the case where `o1` is null - at which point it would throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: I guess I should have refreshed the answers before finishing my answer. :)   +1

Answer (score 4):

Operator == compare objects by reference, and method *Equals* compare objects by value.
For Example:

```
StringBuilder s1 = new StringBuilder(“Yes”);

StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder(“Yes”);

Console.WriteLine(s1 == s2);

Console.WriteLine(s1.Equals(s2));
```

Will display:

```
False

True
```

Value objects can be compared either by == or Equals.

Answer (score 1):

I would use  `Object.Equals(o1,o2)` - ref. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx)

Jon has supplied excellent explanations of why this would be the best usage.

Answer (score 1):

'Equals' should work for strings and the value types you listed.

'==' Will fail for things like the following code because the references to the boxed objects aren't the same:

```
        int x = 1;
        int y = 1;
        Object o1 = x;
        Object o2 = y;
```

Edit:
I noticed the stringbuilder example given above, but since you are using strings and their equality operator is overridden they'd actually work with either "==" or ".Equals", the following code

string s1 = "Yes";

string s2 = "Yes";

Console.WriteLine(s1 == s2);

Console.WriteLine(s1.Equals(s2));

Outputs
True
True

Answer (score 0):

```
object.Equals(obj1, obj2) // This is the way prefered and the best practice for equality comparison.
```

Thus you might also consider overriding the Equals method when working with custom objects (not the case here appearently).

```
public class Something {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        if (((Something)obj) == null)
            return false;

        Something s = (Something)obj;

        return this.Id == s.Id && string.Equals(this.Name, s.Name);
    }

    public bool Equals(Something s) {
        if (s == null)
            return false;

        return this.Id == s.Id && string.Equals(this.Name, s.Name);
    }
}
```

This way, you will assure that your custom objects are equal.