# Cast to Object when comparing a reference warning

Tags: c#

When i am comparing a reference to `this` in a class it gives me a warning of:

> Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type Object

Its a very simple line of code:

```
if (otherTarget != null && otherTarget.TargetComponent == this)
```

It works exactly how I intended it to, but this warning is there and I don't know why? Can I just ignore it, or am I doing something bad with my code logic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible unintended reference comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12263715/possible-unintended-reference-comparison)

Comment: @NatPongjardenlarp According to the answers on that page i have to cast `TargetComponent` to the same type as `this` in order to compare then ? If not, i am confused how to correct it.

Comment: What type is `otherTarget.TargetComponent`? What type is `this`?

Comment: `TargetComponent` is an interface type, which `this` also happens to implement. So i am basically checking it is the same interface reference. @poke

Comment: You need to understand how object equality works, either checkout the official docs or have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379802/net-object-equality

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.net object equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379802/net-object-equality)

Comment: Well now i've been led to two different duplicates with different answers. One uses Equal() and the other does a cast to the same type... i'm just more confused now on what the right answer is.

Comment: If you want to check if both reference the same object, use `object.ReferenceEquals(this, otherTarget.TargetComponent)`

Answer (score 0):

There is a custom operator== for the type of `this` (or its ancestors), but the expression `otherTarget.TargetComponent == this` will use `operator== (object, object)` to do reference comparison, so the warning appears.

If you really want to do reference comparison, cast this to object:

```
otherTarget.TargetComponent == (object)this
```

If you want to use the custom operator==, cast the left object to the type of `this`:

```
(TYPE_OF_THIS)otherTarget.TargetComponent == this
   or
(otherTarget.TargetComponent as TYPE_OF_THIS) == this
```

If you can't decide, disable is a choice:

```
#pragma warning disable 252
```

Comment: Disabling the warning is like a bad alternative to choosing since you are now choosing a “random” decision instead of making an educated choice.